# How do I fetch the values in nested mongo which is an array?

Tags: mongodb

I Have a data of this format

```
{
    
    "producer" : "abc",
    "time" : "2023-01-02T06:30:52.004",
    "type" : "type",
    "transactionId" : "6c809bfd-563f-47d4-a2ef-4941acdc09bf",   
    "additionalData" : {
        "key" : "key",
        "value" : [ 5363, 5355 ]
    }
```

I want to fetch the values in additionaldata.

Answer (score -1):

use this query this should work.

```
db.additionalPayLoadInfo.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$additionalData"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "additionalData.value": 5363
    }
    
  }
]).projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).